# Natural logarithm limit

Tags: analysis, limits, logarithms

Is 
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\ln\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)=0?$$
Because it is $\ln(1+\frac{1}{n})$ and $\frac{1}{n}$ tends to $0$, since $n$ tends to infinity, so the limit becomes $\ln(1+0)=\ln(1)=0$.

Is this right, or is there any remarkable limit related to this?

P.S. I am not used to formatting yet, I didn't really understand the rules, but I did what I could.

Comment: That's right.${}$

Comment: There's a related limit $\lim \ln \left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^n = 1$.

Comment: @sdcvvc well, yes, but that is actually a remarkable limit: $\lim \ln \left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^n = 1$ is $ln\ lim\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n= ln e^{\lim\frac{1}{n}\*n}= ln e^1=1$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\ln$ is continuous at $1$, $\ln 1 = 0$, and $\lim_n \frac{n+1}{n} = 1$, hence $\lim_n \ln(\frac{n+1}{n}) = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, continuity of the logarithm lets you bring the limit inside the logarithm so

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \ln\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)=\ln\left(\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)\right)$$

and yes you can do this for any continuous function besides logarithm.